# Problems with a sorting exercise using swapping

Tags: ruby

So I am trying to create a simple sorting program using the swapping method and I just cant get it to work properly. The code seems solid and it works up until it gets to artichoke. I've gone through and 'puts' the value of array during each iteration and pear swaps with apple, then swaps with orange, then swaps with peach and grapefruit, but when it gets to artichoke it refuses to swap like it should. It also doesn't seem like its an issue with it being the final item in the list because if I add, lets say, banana to the end it still stops at artichoke. Ultimately I want to nest the function inside an 'm.times do' function to continue the swapping until the entire list is sorted but for some reason when I put

```
m.times do
end
```

surrounding the 'n.times do' it creates another error. But I guess it doesn't even matter if I cant even get artichoke to swap with pear. Here is my code below (yes I am aware there is a .sort function, this is for learning purposes).

```
## Ignore this part, it is just a function I made and commented out to create  
## your own list.
=begin
array = []

while true

    puts "what item would you like to add to your list to be sorted?"
    puts "press enter without entering an item to quit"
    item = gets.chomp

    break if item.empty?

    array.push item

end
=end
##

array = ['pear' , 'apple' , 'orange' , 'peach' , 'grapefruit' , 'artichoke']

i = 0
m = array.length
n = m - 1

    n.times do  

        if array.to_s[i] >= array.to_s[i+1]
            swap = array[i]
            array[i] = array[i+1]
            array[i+1] = swap
         end

        i += 1

    end

puts array
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
array = ['pear' , 'apple' , 'orange' , 'peach' , 'grapefruit' , 'artichoke']

m = array.length
n = m - 1

    n.times do  
        i = 0
        n.times do
            if array[i] >= array[i+1]
                temp = array[i]
                array[i] = array[i+1]
                array[i+1] = temp
             end
            i += 1
        end
    end
puts array
```

In this method of sorting, called "bubble sorting", you need nested loops. After just one run only the topmost element is guaranteed to be at its correct position. This is also known as infamous O(n*n) complexity of this poor algorithm. Btw. The inner loop can be shorther, like `n-i` times.

Fixed some mistakes:

- `array.to_s[i]` is wrong because index has to be applied to array, not `to_s` method
- ... and its not necessary to call `to_s` since elements of this particular array already are strings
- `i = 0` had to be moved to the beggining of the outer loop
- term "swap" refers to action, while variable is usually called "temp"

Comment: Thanks this worked. Sorry, I forgot to mention it was bubble sort. I realize its big O makes it a poor algorithm to use but I'm new to programming and this is for learning purposes.

You were right about the to_s, I think I added it somewhere along the line because it ended up fixing a problem I had before the code was nearly complete. I'm still sort of unsure as to what exactly it does.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean to do `array[i] >= array[i+1]`

`array.to_s` will make a string out of your entire array and so you are comparing a character at a time of your stringified array instead of a word at a time as you seem to be intending to do.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know it was doing that. Now I understand to_s a bit more